# Bifurcation in coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the coupled differential equations $$x'(t) = -33x(t) + 3x(t)y(t),$$ $$y'(t) = 5y(t) - \frac{5y^{2}(t)}{11} - 2x(t)y(t).$$ This system has equilibrium points at $(0, 0)$ - a saddle point and (0, 11) - a bifurcation point.- (*).

Does the plane I've shown below agree with my statement (*)?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a bifurcation point?

Comment: I'm not totally aware what bifurcation is, my lecturer says if we have a point with one or both eigenvalues equalling zero then we have bifurcation. For (0, 11) I have one eigenvalue as 0 and a second as -5. Does this agree with the maple plot?

Comment: Bifurcations normally have to do with parameters. When such parameters make the spectrum of a system cross the imaginary axis, then it is said that a bifurcation occurs. I do not think the definition of a bifurcation is only that 1 or more eigenvalues are 0. Your plot might be correct with the system, but something is missing to be able to talk of bifurcations. More precisely there is a $1$-dimensional center manifold (a local invariant) that contains the non-hyperbolic equilibrium point $(x,y)=(0,11)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your critical points.

If we find the Jacobian and evaluate its eigenvalues at the CP $(0,11)$, we have one eigenvalue zero and one $-5$.

I am not sure how you are using bifurcation here, but look at the phase portrait below and compare to yours.

I would try to draw a phase portrait that shows the details of that region more clearly. Maybe change some of the ranges of your PP since we do not care about the negative axis so much (except for $(0,0))$.  @user58533 gave a nice description in his/her comment.

Here is a PP view showing the two CPs, but also look above and to the left of $(0, 11)$:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I can see a saddle at (0, 0), what type of equilibrium point is there at (0, 11)? For x < 0 it looks similar to a saddle point but for x > 0 we have something I'm not familiar with. Ps. What software did you use to plot this graph and what do PP and CP stand for?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these explanations. The information I know is: If the eigenvalues are real and negative we have a stable node. If they are real and negative we have an unstable node. If one is negative and one is positive we have a saddle point. If they are complex and the real part of each is equal and positive we have an unstable spiral. If the real parts are equal and negative we have a stable spiral and if the real parts are equal to zero we have a centre. I don't have any information about if one eigenvalue is zero and another is either < 0. What is this classified as?

Comment: Saddle point -- one positive and one negative eigenvalue
Unstable node -- two positive real eigenvalues
Stable node -- two negative real eigenvalues
Unstable vortex or spiral -- complex eigenvalues with positive real parts
Stable vortex or spiral -- complex eigenvalues with negative real parts
In addition there are a number of degenerate cases:
Center -- a pair of pure imaginary eigenvalues
Degenerate node -- two identical eigenvalues
**Line field -- a zero eigenvalue**, see: http://www.cnbc.cmu.edu/~bard/xppfast/lin2d.html